# Pandas: insert column based on matching column from another dataset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two pandas dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'foo'=[1,2,3,4,5})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'bar'=[1,3,5], 'newCol' =[a,b,c]})
```

I want to add the column 'newCol' to df1 where columns df1['foo'] and df2['bar'] match.

Required output:

```
+-----+--------+
| foo | newCol |
+-----+--------+
| 1   | a      |
+-----+--------+
| 2   |        |
+-----+--------+
| 3   | b      |
+-----+--------+
| 4   |        |
+-----+--------+
| 5   | c      |
+-----+--------+
```

Comment: They don't match; value at `df1.loc[3, 'foo'] != df2.loc[3, 'bar']`. Do you mean when a value in `df1` is in `df2['bar']`?

Comment: Please read about merge function in Google

Comment: @ifly6, yes that is what I was referring to.